# Magical Record truncate is very slow

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Why can the truncate operation in MagicalRecord be very slow? I need to delete all objects of two types from the database, and this is how I'm doing it now:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread];
    [Term MR_truncateAllInContext:context];
    [Group MR_truncateAllInContext:context];
});
```

The first truncation is always fast, but the second one can take up to 20 seconds or even more. There are 6 groups in the database and about 6000 terms, but it doesn't matter, because even if you switch the order of these operations, the first one is always fast, and the second one is always slow. As far as I can tell, the operation which takes all this time is

```
results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Which is located in the "NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m" file. What can I be doing wrong? I've tried putting the truncation in a global queue, using different contexts and updating MagicalRecord to the 3.0 beta version (I'm using the version 2.2 now), but it didn't help.
There are no operations happening with the database during the execution of this code. Please help if you have any ideas, because this bug doesn't make any sense to me. I've been using Xcode 6.1.1 and the iOS 8.1 simulator while testing this.

Comment: Time to ask the question if MR is really worth the trouble. :(